# Plotting errorbars in the logarithmic domain with negative values (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, plot, logarithm

I have a vector, call it x, which contains very small numbers that I calculated from a mean.  I'd like to plot the logarithmic transform of x, say y=10*log10(x), along with errorbars equal to +- 2 standard deviations calculated when finding the mean.

To do this, I'm using the following code:

```
figure
errorbar(lengths, 10*log10(x), ...
    10*log10(x-2*std_x), 10*log10(x+2*std_x), 'o')
```

My problem is that since x contains such small values, x-2*std_x is usually a negative number, and you can't take the log of negative numbers.

So I suppose my question is how can I plot errorbars in the logarithmic domain when subtracting the standard deviation in the linear domain gives me negative numbers?  I can't do the +-

Comment: this also means that the error bar meaning isn't quite right - the error bars assume a gaussian distribution, and nonnegativity means that it's not gaussian. but I still understand why you would do this, and it's still reasonable :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace those values with a small value but log-able (say, 40 dB lower):

```
minb = x-2*std_x;
mask = (minb <= 0);
minb(mask) = x/1e4;
... use 10*log10(minb) instead
```

Or just threshold to some minimum:

```
K = min(x) / 1e4; % so that K is 40 db below the smallest x
... use 10*log10(max(K, x-2*std_x)) instead.
```

Or similar stuff.

**EDIT** to summarize comments and further thoughts:

One should probably think about *why* have error bars. Normally error bars tend to indicate some measure of confidence / probability (e.g. x% of the time, the value is between the indicated bounds). In this case, where some logarithm is taken of a quantity, it is likely that the quantity is drawn from a non-negative distribution. In that case, it is probably more correct to use bounds that are not mean +/- K * std_deviation to indicate bounds.

Assuming a unimodal distribution with cdf F(x), the "proper" bounds (i.e. smallest, for a given probability) would probably be such that

F'(x1) = F'(x2), F(x2) - F(x1) = desired_probability, and x1 <= mode <= x2.

This is mean +/- K std_deviation for a symmetric distribution, but as mentioned, a strictly positive distribution probably requires a different treatment.

Comment: Statistically speaking, is this an accurate solution?  Ideally I would like the errorbars to be +- 2 standard deviation, but by making the lower errorbars -40 dB from the mean for instances where that is not possible makes it seem misleading.

Comment: Well, it is going to be misleading anyway (because x-2std_x is negative). Can `x` even be negative in the first place? If not, then doing - 2 std_x is probably conceptually faulty.

Comment: Normally I can think of taking +/- about the mean for a unimodal distribution as saying something like `P(low < X < high) = some_value`. For a symmetric distribution (in particular, say, normal distribution), taking `low = mean-K std` and `high = mean+K std` makes sense because the range is the smallest possible. If `x` is a skewed distribution, then maybe it makes more sense to find 2 separate bounds to encapsulate the required information.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you're calling `errorbar` wrong. You should call

```
figure
errorbar(lengths, 10*log10(x),10*log10(2*std_x), 'o')
```

If `std_x` is too small for this to work, you can write your own version of `errorbar` by plotting vertical lines from `10*log10(x-2*std_x)` to `10*log10(x+2*std_x)`

Answer (score 2):

use errorbar in the two error configuration, then change the y-axis to be logarithmic:

```
eps = 1E-4;  %whatever you consider to be a very small fraction
ebl = min(2*std_x, x*(1-eps));
ebu = 2*std_x;
errorbar(lengths, x, ebl, ebu, 'o');
set(gca, 'YScale', 'log');
```

you may want to adjust your yaxis range manually using `ylim`